# openCL : No. of iterations in profiling API

Tags: opencl

Trying to use [clGetEventProfilingInfo](http://www.khronos.org/registry/cl/sdk/1.0/docs/man/xhtml/clGetEventProfilingInfo.html) for timing my kernels.

Is there any facility to give no. of iterations before which the values of start time and end time are reported?

If the kernel is run only once then , of ourse it has lots of over heads associated with it. So to get the best timing we should run the kernel several times and take the average time.

Do we have such a parameter in profiling using API? (We do have such parameters when we use third party software Tools for profiling)

Answer (score 1):

The `clGetEventProfilingInfo` function will return profiling information for a single event, which corresponds to a single enqueued command. There is no built-in mechanism to automatically report information across a number of calls; you'll have to code that yourself.

It's pretty straightforward to do - just query the start and end times for each event you care about and add them up. If you are only running a single kernel (in a loop), then you could just use a wall-clock timer (with `clFinish` before you start and stop timing), or take the difference between the time the first event started and the last event finished.

Comment: Agreed. We keep a running total and count and output the average when we're done.

Comment: @jprice ' If you are only running a single kernel (in a loop)' how would you run a single kernel in a loop? Do you mean to say I put clenquendsrangekernel(...); in a for loop?

Comment: @user2799508 You don't have to, but that's typically how I benchmark kernel runtimes for simple applications that only have a single kernel to execute repeatedly.

Comment: @jprice I mean in OpenCL how would I put kernel launches in a loop? I mean can you write a line of code for that?